# hadoop fs -ls s3://bucket or s3a://bucket throws "No such file or directory" error

Tags: amazon-s3, hdfs, amazon-emr

In a newly created EMR cluster, using:

- `hdfs dfs -ls s3://bucket`
- `hadoop fs -ls s3://bucket`
- `hadoop fs -ls s3a://`
- etc.

...all return the error:

"ls: `s3://bucket': No such file or directory"

- EMR instance profile has full S3 access
- Nothing specified in `core-site.xml`
- `aws s3 ls` can correctly list all buckets

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, `hadoop fs -ls` [shows user home directory](https://akbarahmed.com/2012/07/15/hadoop-fs-ls/#:%7E:text=hadoop%20fs%20%2Dls%20defaults%20to,contents%20of%20your%20home%20directory.), which translates to `/user/username`.

When calling `hadoop fs -ls s3://bucket`, the S3 connector will try to find `s3://bucket/user/hadoop` (substitute tailing `hadoop` with your username) which may not exist and will lead to the error.

The error is not clear, but is different from `ls`ing a non-existant bucket. For that the error would be `ls: Bucket bucket_name does not exist`.

To avoid this:

- Append a `/` after the bucket name
- Add full path

To debug this:

- `export HADOOP_ROOT_LOGGER=DEBUG,console`

To turn off debug log

- `export HADOOP_ROOT_LOGGER=WARN,console`

Comment: (yes, this is a recurrent PITA. too late to fix the hadoop fs shell though). There's been discussion about "should we make / the home dir of an s3a bucket?", but we decided against it as it'd be inconsistent across versions